# While loop in C++ (using break)

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm currently working through the book C++ Primer (recommended on SO book list). An exercise was given that was essentially read through some strings, check if any strings were repeated twice in succession, if a string was repeated print which word and break out of the loop. If no word was repeated, print that. Here is my solution, I'm wondering a) if it's not a good solution and b) is my test condition for no repeated words ok? Because I had to add 1 to the variable to get it to work as expected. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {


vector<string> words = {"Cow", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Bird"};

string tempWord;
unsigned int i = 0;

while (i != words.size())
{
  if (words[i] == tempWord)
  {
    cout << "Loop exited as the word " << tempWord << " was repeated.";
    break;
  } 
  else 
  {
    tempWord = words[i];
  }
    // add 1 to i to test equality as i starts at 0
    if (i + 1 == words.size())
        cout << "No word was repeated.";

    ++i;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first time the loop runs it will test agains an empty string in `tempWord`. Then, it will only find the duplicates if they follow each other, so if your input array is e.g. `{"Cow", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Bird"}` it won't find the duplicates.

Comment: Hmmmm, at a glance, it looks like you're only checking for contiguous repeats, is that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: You code will not detect repeating word if they are separated. For example, "Cat", "Dog", "Cow", "Cat"

Comment: @George yeah the book said to just check for words twice in succession

Comment: @Steeve thanks for the comment. But for the purpose of the exercise it said just to check for repeats twice in succession

Comment: Cool, the only things I would suggest  would be initializing `tempworld`, breaking at ` if (i + 1 == words.size())` and maybe caching `words.size()` to guarantee that it's only called once, anything else is just getting even more nitpicky, it's a good attempt :)

Comment: @George thank you..  yeah that's my bad not initializing tempWord. I usually inititialuze every variable to avoid junk values. I'm not sure what you mean by caching to guarantee it only gets called once. How would I do that? If you don't mind explaining.

Comment: I'd move the check `if (i + 1 == words.size())` outside of the loop, since you only need to check this once, when you are finished.

Comment: By caching I just mean create an int variable and store the size in it before the while loop, something like `int size = words.size()`. Also, as @StoryTeller pointed out, you could move `if (i + 1 == words.size())` out of the while loop but in this way you'll still need the while loop check, if you wanted to be really cool you could move that if below the loop and change your while condition to `while(i < size)`.

Comment: You should probably post questions like these on CodeReview.SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for a code review

Comment: @George `words.size()` is guaranteed to have constant-time complexity

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 it still requires a function call, which again most compilers would optimize out, but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @George I'd say that in vast majority of cases it will be optimized out, but the point is that when we write `words.size()` any reader understands what is means, and usage of a cache variable is less obvious. Readability is almost always more important than performance. If `words.size()` had a linear-time complexity, it would be sensible to use caching variable sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the test condition outside of the loop, as it seems unnecessary to perform it at every step. For readability I would add a `bool`:

```
string tempWord;
unsigned int i = 0;
bool exited = false;

while (i != words.size())
{
  if (words[i] == tempWord)
  {
    cout << "Loop exited as the word " << tempWord << " was repeated.";
    exited = true;
    break;
  } 
  else 
  {
    tempWord = words[i];
  }
    ++i;
}

// Doing the check afterwards instead
if (!exited) 
{
    cout << "No word was repeated.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "good solution" will somewhat depend on the requirements - the most important will always be "does it work" - but then there may be speed and memory requirements on top.

Yours seems to work (unless you have the first string being blank, in which case it'll break); so it's certainly not that bad.

The only suggestion I could make is that you could have a go at writing a version that doesn't keep a copy of one of the strings, because what if they're really really big / lots of them and copying them will be an expensive process?

Answer (score 0):

> a) if it's not a good solution

For the input specified it is a good solution (it works). However, tempWord is not initialized, so the first time the loop runs it will test against an empty string. Because the input does not contain an empty string, it works. But if your input started with an empty string it would falsely find as repeating.

> b) is my test condition for no repeated words ok? Because I had to add 1 to the variable to get it to work as expected.

Yes, and it is simply because the indexing of the array starts from zero, and you are testing it against the count of items in the array. So for example an array with count of 1 will have only one element which will be indexed as zero. So you were right to add 1 to i.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer for the training task your code (after some fixes suggested in other answers) look good. However, if this was a real world problem (and therefore it didn't contain strange restrictions like "use a for loop and break"), then its writer should also consider ways of improving readability.

Usage of default STL algorithm is almost always better than reinventing the wheel, so I would write this code as follows:

```
auto equal = std::find_adjacent(words.begin(), words.end());
if (equal == words.end())
{
    cout << "No word was repeated" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Word " << *equal << " was repeated" << endl;
}
```